# Aptitude: everything is marked as auto removable

Tags: aptitude

I have botched some settings up pretty bad with synaptic/aptitude.

A while back I did something with synaptic that marked all of my installed packages as "manual". I was trying to fix this but ended up setting them to be all flagged as auto removable. Any idea how to get back to square one with aptitude/synaptic?

Comment: I don't know about getting back to square one but setting all to manually installed is preferable to all marked auto installed (the second may make aptitude want to remove everything f there is a change). Aptitude is pretty good about marking unused packages for removal.

Comment: This question would probably be more helpful for most people: https://askubuntu.com/questions/438620/apt-get-install-is-there-a-command-to-work-on-a-batch-of-packages